# Changing envelope size of an vertex with the Skin modifyer hot key

Tags: modifiers

I want to work with the skin modifyer to produce a organic beam to put something on top. So i want to change the envelope size at the red marked are, so there is a hotkey which I already forgott 3times... So what is the key in blender 2.8 for that feature?

[image: Organic Barier]

Comment: i don't exactly understand but you might be looking for alt+S or if still not applied skin modifier ctrl+A

Comment: jepp, ctrl+A I was lookng for. Already found it in the manual of the skin Modifier, but thanks anyway!